# Same class/layout in view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am trying to add the same class several times to a viewpager to show different info which is read from a sqlite DB. The thing is when the view is created, always override the objects, textviews etc..., in the current view and not in the fragment for each page.

```
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int d : descritions) {
        Description temp = DBCompanies.getDescriptionById(db_path,
                GSSettings.DBCODE, d, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage(),
                GSSettings.DEFAULTLANGUAGE, false);
        names.add(temp.getTitle());

    }
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    // mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    mViewPager.refreshDrawableState();
...
```

How can I avoid this behavior?

thanks.

EDIT:

I added more code to clarify my question:

framecompany100.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ly_main"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="500"
android:scrollbarFadeDuration="200"
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb_company" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/ga_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ly_details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ga_image" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_options"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_button_options" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ly_details_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_options" 
            android:background="#77ffffff" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_address" android:text="kldfjhskdjhfksj"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ly_details"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the class for this layout:

FrameCompany100.java

```
public class FrameCompany100 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener,
    PictureUpdater, FragmentName {

private Bundle data = new Bundle();
private Gallery image;
private Description description;
private BaseAdapter adapter;
private String db_path;
private GuiParams main_params;
private Company company;
private String name = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    data = this.getArguments();
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        data = savedInstanceState;

    db_path = "/data/data/" + getActivity().getPackageName()
            + GSSettings.DB_PATH;

    description = DBCompanies.getDescriptionById(db_path,
            GSSettings.DBCODE, data.getInt("descriptionId"), Locale
                    .getDefault().getLanguage(), "es", false);
    company = DBCompanies.getCompany(db_path, GSSettings.DBCODE,
            description.getCompanyId());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.framecompany100, container, false);
}

void init() {
    try {
        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager()
                .getDefaultDisplay();
        int height = display.getHeight();
        final int width = display.getWidth();

        // params
        main_params = DBCompanies.getGuiParams(db_path, GSSettings.DBCODE,
                description.getCompanyId(), GSSettings.body);
        if (main_params == null || main_params.getBackgroundcolor() == null
                || main_params.getBackgroundcolor().equals("")
                || main_params.getTextcolor() == null
                || main_params.getTextcolor().equals(""))
            main_params = DBApp.getGuiParam(db_path, GSSettings.DBCODE,
                    GSSettings.body);

        // main Layout
        RelativeLayout ly_main = (RelativeLayout) getActivity()
                .findViewById(R.id.ly_main);
        try {
            ly_main.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(main_params
                    .getBackgroundcolor()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        Typeface font_body = null;
        try {
            font_body = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
                    "fonts/" + main_params.getFont());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            font_body = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                    getActivity().getAssets(),
                    "fonts/"
                            + DBApp.getGuiParam(db_path, GSSettings.DBCODE,
                                    GSSettings.body).getFont());
        }

        TextView tv_description = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.tv_description);
        try {
            tv_description.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(main_params
                    .getTextcolor()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        if (description == null) {
            tv_description.setText(R.string.nodescription);
        } else {
            tv_description.setText(description.getText());
        }

        TextView tv_address = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.tv_address);
        try {
            tv_address.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(main_params
                    .getTextcolor()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
.....
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    init();
    // ((MainLayout) getActivity()).setDescription(description);
    super.onResume();
}
```

the FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Description temp = DBCompanies.getDescriptionById(db_path,
                GSSettings.DBCODE, descritions[i], Locale.getDefault()
                        .getLanguage(), GSSettings.DEFAULTLANGUAGE, false);

        Fragment fragment = null;
        try {
            fragment = new CompanyLayout100();
            ((FragmentName) fragment).setName(temp.getTitle());
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("descriptionId", temp.getId());
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return descritions.length;
        // return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String name = "";
        try {
            name = names.get(position);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```

what's happening is, the viewpager create the view for these frames but always is entering the data in the visible frame. I think is because the layout.xml is the same so there is only one id and all object are pointing at the visible layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a FragmentPagerAdapter that creates the instance ...

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    int pages;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pages;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return MyFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    public void setPages(int no) {
        pages = no;
    }
}
```

So in the main activity you attach the PagerAdapter ...

```
   adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
   adapter.setPages(noPages);
   pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Finally you need your Fragment including the newInstance method. Check out this http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html for more.

Cheers!

**Edit #1**: MyFragment; **note**: it is essential to pass the position as an argument

```
public class MyFragment extends SherlockFragment {
  private static final String KEY_POSITION="position";

  static MyFragment newInstance(int position) {
    MyFragment frag=new MyFragment();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();

    args.putInt(KEY_POSITION, position);
    frag.setArguments(args);

    return(frag);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.editor, container, false);
    EditText editor=(EditText)result.findViewById(R.id.editor);
    int position=getArguments().getInt(KEY_POSITION, -1);

    editor.setHint(String.format(getString(R.string.hint), position + 1));

    return(result);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a fragmentpageadapter, the different to your proposal is that I create the list of fragment and pass it when I create the adapter, mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments); then I return the fragment, public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(i);}

Comment: You mean that the fragment should be created in the FragmentPagerAdapter?

Comment: That is the way I saw it in many examples and how I implemented it. Works pretty fine. This example looks even easier: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Fragments

Comment: Thanks, I will try changing the place where I create the object/frames. Just for my understanding, Why of this? If I pass an array with the frames to the FragmentPagerAdapter, what is the different if the FragmentPagerAdapter create the frames in Fragment getItem(int position) method??

Comment: I have tried your proposal but it is not solving the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more of your source code here? The github example above looked pretty well and if you sticjk to it you should be close to the solution. Guess it's just a snmall missing  piece in your puzzle ...

Comment: Hi André, do not waste time now, I am going to check something which come to my mind right now. I am at work so I cannot check until this night. I will tell you later. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I attched some important code from the fragment: check if you followed this example ... good luck!

Comment: hi, I have to check but I think my error was using the getActivity().findByIDd(..) in the init(). So I was entering data in the views of the activity which is the visible fragment.... I think I have to use getview().findById(..) I'll check later

Comment: I already checked. My error was taken the view from the activity and not from the fragment view. Problem solved. Thanks for your help.